# How to check if a proxy is connectable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, networking, proxy

I have a list of public proxies that I have scraped from the web, but many of them are not actually connectable. I would like to filter this list using Ruby.

How would I craft a function such that it returns true if I can successfully connect to the proxy and false otherwise?

Here's the general idea:

```
def connectable?(proxy)
  ip, port = proxy.split(':')
  return true if connect(ip, port) == success
  false
end
```

Comment: Where is connect coming from?

Answer (score 3):

Just try to connect to it like you did, not forgetting to close the connection if it succeeds. Ping doesn't test the right things.

Answer (score 2):

You could use 'ping' library:

```
require 'net/ping'

def connectable?(proxy)
  host, port = proxy.split(':')
  return Net::Ping::TCP.new(host, port).ping
end
```

If you have to use ip address instead of host name, 'Resolv.getname()' method from 'resolve' module can help you

Comment: Net::Ping::TCP class works upon the TCPSocket. As say in documentation "With a TCP ping simply try to open a connection. If we are successful, assume success."

Comment: But it doesn't connect to the same port that the proxy uses. It only establishes whether the host is there, not the proxy server.

Comment: Topic starter wrote: "many of them are not actually connectable...  if I can successfully connect to the proxy". The code in snippet establish TCP connection to given host on given port (it can be any port). Please correct me if I wrong or misunderstood problem specification.